# Drag and drop is going below of the droppable area and dragging whole item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Drag and drop is not properly happening in my example. I would like to drag items between `Project 1`, `Project 2`, `Project 3`
While dragging an item it is going under of the `div` and second problem is that, while dragging a single item its dragging the whole item from project 2 and 3. Could someone help me to fix the problem.
I have created fiddle to demonstrate the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/du82of0y/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.box-item').draggable({
    cursor: 'move'
});
$("#container1").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var itemid = $(event.originalEvent.toElement).attr("id");
    $('.peopleClass >.box-item').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("id") === itemid) {
        $(this).appendTo("#container1");
      }
    });
  }
});
$("#container2").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var itemid = $(event.originalEvent.toElement).attr("id");
    $('.box-item').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("id") === itemid) {
        $(this).appendTo("#container2");
      }
    });
   }
  });
 $("#container3").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var itemid = $(event.originalEvent.toElement).attr("id");
    $('.box-item').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("id") === itemid) {
        $(this).appendTo("#container3");
      }
    });
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: Any reason to not use existing library? Like [dragula](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/) for [example](https://codepen.io/morovic/pen/ZRvVNw).

Comment: I have heard about dragula earlier, but not sure if that has good support of users all over the world. I will try that now.